# HTML says radio button is checked, but javascript says it's not

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

Here's the html for my button, according to Chrome:

```
<input checked="" type="radio" class="edit bindable" id="communicationAddresses[0].defaultAddress" name="EMAIL.default">
```

When I run this in my javascript console, the output output is "false"

```
$("input[type=radio]:first").attr("checked")
```

The actual UI element is visibly not selected. When I run this code, the button becomes visibly selected:

```
$("input[type=radio]:first").attr("checked", true)
```

Looking back at the html in Chrome, I see almost exactly the same thing I saw before. The only difference is that "checked" is now at the end of the tag instead of the beginning?

```
<input type="radio" class="edit bindable" id="communicationAddresses[0].defaultAddress" name="EMAIL.default" checked="">
```

A bit more information: there is another radio group lower down on the page. When I remove this second radio group, the first acts as expected. They are distinct groups. It *is* possible to manually select buttons from each one.

What's going on here? Why wasn't the button visibly selected to begin with?

##### EDIT

The button *was* selected to begin with, but wound up getting deselected due to a bug in some event binding code I was running.

Comment: What's the structure of the html? And, as an aside, `checked` is a Boolean attribute; it doesn't require a value it just has to be there: so `<input type="radio" checked />` not `<input type="radio" checked="" />`.

Comment: if you want it to be checked use checked="checked" or don't use checked property at all

Comment: @David Thomas I'm using <input type="radio" checked /> in my html. The browser is showing me checked="" when I view source though. I'd rather not dump all of my html and ask you all to pour over it for mistakes.

Comment: Ok. Figured out why it wasn't loaded as checked. Had to do with some fancy/stupid binding code I was running on it that was buggy. Thanks for your help folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `checked` attribute corresponds to the checkbox's *default* checkedness, not its *current* checkedness.

In other words, the `checked` attribute corresponds to the [`defaultChecked` javascript property](http://wwww.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_defaultchecked.asp), and not the [`checked` property](http://wwww.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp).

jQuery's `$("foo").attr("checked", true)` sets the `checked` javascript property, but doesn't affect the `checked` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Emmet. So, that answers the main part of the question. Any guesses why it didn't appear as checked to begin with?

Comment: @morgancodes I'm probably misunderstanding your situation... according to your first code snippet, it starts with `checked=""`, so why are you expecting it to appear checked to begin with?

Comment: Let's forget about the second part. I figured that out. And you answered the first part. Thanks!